# Material that holds shape when stretched

Tags: materials

I'm looking for a lightweight material that will hold its shape when stretched out. Something like a rubber band that doesn't snap back. So it starts out small, but once it's stretched it stays large. (Apologies if there's a name for such a property that I don't know.)

Thanks!

Comment: If you cut a loop from a black plastic bin liner you’ll get this type of behaviour

Comment: Steel; spring back is 0.2 % ( for very high strength steel it is 0.5%).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a material that has [plastic deformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(engineering)#Plastic_deformation) properties and is highly [ductile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ductility). To achieve your desired material behavior, you'll want a polymer like [Parafilm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parafilm), which you can [buy online](https://smile.amazon.com/Parafilm-PM-996-Purpose-Laboratory-Film/dp/B004VQP6CQ/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=parafilm&qid=1558046487&s=gateway&sr=8-1).

edit: More generally, you should look at different thermoplastics and find one that meets your needs. Available material properties at room temperature range from extreme malleability/ductility (“floppy” plastic like Parafilm) to relative stiffness and structural integrity (you need to heat these materials, although this can be easily achieved with readily available hot water in examples like [Ingo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kp8tduAkbus)).

Comment: Thanks for helping with both a suggested material and the terminology I needed!

Answer (score 0):

**Ductile and Plastic Material for Making Parts? Suggest you try Polycaprolactone.**

If you're looking for a highly ductile/purely plastic material to form into a shape -- one that's easy to work with at home, you might try:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycaprolactone#Hobbyist_and_prototyping 
granules, after warming in hot water. There are a host of brand-names all selling essentially the same granules: Polymorph, Thermomorph, and Friendly Plastic are just a few. Quite safe; medicos use this stuff to splint fingers sometimes.